# Cast date and time stored as text to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I have the following table `NTESQ004HDR`:

```
runid   TrainNumber divcode ScheduledDT schedarrtime  scheddepdate  -- needed format of schedarrtime
  a        16127      NYY      2006        2241          2242       --20/06/2018 22:41:00.00
  a        16127      TVC      2006        2315          2320
  a        16127      CRY      2006        2341          2342
  a        16127      KVU      2006        2349          2350
  a        16127      VAK      2006        0000          0000       --21/06/2018 00:00:00.00
  a        16127      PVU      2006        0015          0016
  a        16127      QLN      2006        0030          0035       --21/06/2018 00:30:00.00
  a        16127      KYJ      2006        0118          0120
  a        16127      HAD      2006        0135          0136
  a        16127      AMPA     2006        0150          0151
  a        16128      TVC      2006        2315          2320
  a        16128      CRY      2006        2341          2342
  a        16128      KVU      2006        2349          2350
  a        16128      PVU      2006        0015          0016
  a        16128      QLN      2006        0030          0035
  a        16128      KYJ      2006        0118          0120
  a        16128      HAD      2006        0135          0136
  a        16128      AMPA     2006        0150          0151
```

It says, `16127` train's scheduled arrival time for `NYY` station is `20/06/2018 22:41:00.00` and departure time is `20/06/2018 22:42:00.00`. These times are returned by (what I'm tried...)

```
declare @year varchar(10) = (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()))
select RUNID, divcode 
  , TRY_CONVERT(datetime, right(ScheduledDT,2)+'-'+left(ScheduledDT,2)+'-'+@year+' '+left(scheddepdate,2)+':'+RIGHT(scheddepdate,2)+':00.00') 'schdeptime'
  , TRY_CONVERT(datetime, right(ScheduledDT,2)+'-'+left(ScheduledDT,2)+'-'+@year+' '+left(schedarrtime,2)+':'+RIGHT(schedarrtime,2)+':00.00') 'scharrtime'
  , TrainNumber
from NTESQ004HDR
```

Where as, it returns `20/06/2018 00:30:00.00` as `schedarrtime` for `QLN` station.
But my need is `21/06/2018 00:30:00.00`.

My expected output:

```
runid   TrainNumber divcode         schedarrtime                     scheddepdate   
  a        16127      NYY      20/06/2018 22:41:00.00           20/06/2018 22:42:00.00
  a        16127      TVC      20/06/2018 23:15:00.00           20/06/2018 23:20:00.00
  a        16127      CRY      20/06/2018 23:41:00.00           20/06/2018 23:42:00.00
  a        16127      KVU      20/06/2018 23:49:00.00           20/06/2018 23:50:00.00
  a        16127      VAK      21/06/2018 00:00:00.00           21/06/2018 00:00:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16127      PVU      21/06/2018 00:15:00.00           21/06/2018 00:16:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16127      QLN      21/06/2018 00:30:00.00           21/06/2018 00:35:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16127      KYJ      21/06/2018 01:18:00.00           21/06/2018 01:20:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16127      HAD      21/06/2018 01:35:00.00           21/06/2018 01:36:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16127      AMPA     21/06/2018 01:50:00.00           21/06/2018 01:51:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16128      TVC      20/06/2018 23:15:00.00           20/06/2018 23:20:00.00
  a        16128      CRY      20/06/2018 23:41:00.00           20/06/2018 23:42:00.00
  a        16128      KVU      20/06/2018 23:49:00.00           20/06/2018 23:50:00.00
  a        16128      PVU      21/06/2018 00:15:00.00           21/06/2018 00:16:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16128      QLN      21/06/2018 00:30:00.00           21/06/2018 00:35:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16128      KYJ      21/06/2018 01:18:00.00           21/06/2018 01:20:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16128      HAD      21/06/2018 01:35:00.00           21/06/2018 01:36:00.00  |here my table gets changes
  a        16128      AMPA     21/06/2018 01:50:00.00           21/06/2018 01:51:00.00  |here my table gets changes
```

**Note**:

1. Runid is uniquely generated for each 5 mintues.
2. Multiple train numbers are available in ONE RUNID.
3. All columns are of type varchar.
4. Data are come from Railway server (according to Dev team quotes) and date format is **INDIAN RAILWAY FORMAT**.
5. Then, I'll find the Next and Previous Major Stations of Current Station.(It depends on my expected table).
6. I'm using SQL Server 2012

**UPDATED 1:**
Train 16127 reach `KVU` station at `20/06/2018  23:49:00.00`. After few minutes it reachs `VAK` at `21/06/2018  00:00:00.00`. But `20/06/2018` date is remains on `ScheduledDT`. Where as What I need, add one date when `schedarrtime` cross `2359`.

**UPDATED 2:**

In this case My Front End Team(Web Developers), solve this issue. That they 
insert the `ScheduledDT` column as `next date` when travel on next day, by evaluate the current time of travelling train. So I have correct date in `ScheduledDT` column as follows,

```
runid   TrainNumber divcode ScheduledDT schedarrtime    scheddepdate
  b        6004      TEN        2106        1530            1635
  b        6004      CVP        2106        1637            1700
  b        6004      SRT        2106        1702            1730
  b        6004      VPT        2106        1732            1830
  b        6004      MDU        2106        1835            1837
  b        6004      KQN        2106        1902            1925
  b        6004      DG         2206        0030            0035        --here date is 2206 as well as time is 0030
  b        6004      MDU        2206        0240            0319
  b        6004      VPT        2206        0320            0327
```

Thank you all

Comment: is the year always 2018 or the current year? Side note, store dates as dates and you avoid this.

Comment: @scsimon question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since all columns are `varchar`, you can just `concatenate` it. No need for `TRY_CONVERT`.  Dates don't have format in SQL Server... and since you want it returned in that format, it must be a `varchar`.

```
--load up your sample data
with cte as(
    select 
        runid = 'a'
        ,TrainNumber = '16127'
        ,divcode = 'NYY'
        ,ScheduleDT = '2006'
        ,schedarrtime = '2241'
        ,sheddeptdate = '2242'
)

--here's the formula. Repeat this with sheddeptdate.
select *
    ,new_schedarrtime = left(ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + right (ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4) ) + ' ' + left(schedarrtime,2) + ':' + right(schedarrtime,2) + ':' + '00.00'
from cte
```

So, the two lines you need:

```
,new_schedarrtime = left(ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + right (ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4) ) + ' ' + left(schedarrtime,2) + ':' + right(schedarrtime,2) + ':' + '00.00'
,new_scheddeptdate = left(ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + right (ScheduleDT,2) + '/' + cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4) ) + ' ' + left(sheddeptdate,2) + ':' + right(sheddeptdate,2) + ':' + '00.00'
```

Comment: Thx for effort.. But worng result remains for this data `,schedarrtime = '0030'`. When I'm using this INPUT, `cte` returns `21/06/2018 00:30:00.00`

Comment: What should it be? That is the correct time for midnight... you aren't specifying AM and PM. So, universal time is used.

Comment: Haaa... Sorry. Itz my bad. `21/06/2018 00:30:00.00` is AM as per **INDIAN RAILWAY TIME**

Comment: Your comments are inconsistent. If it's AM its fine. If it's PM it should be 1230, not 0030 and the date should have +1 day. From your data it's clear that it's a 24-hour clock ... If there's some twisted logic just use a CASE statement but however twisted the logic, it has to be consistent. If it's not - your data won't be as well.

Comment: if this works then you should consider accepting the answer. I think @KamilG. Comments are very valid too

Comment: @KamilG.. Yes correct..+1 for you...!! 1230 is pm of `20/06/2018`.........`0030` is am of next day(that is `21/06/2018`). Which means train reach `VAK` on next day from stared date. We can find that train runs on next, by using `schedarrtime`.